# What might cause this strange pattern on an LCD monitor?

Tags: lcd, laptop, fault

Recently my laptop has been showing a strange effect on its monitor:

[image: Strange LCD error]

This is supposed to be a black screen, but the bottom fifth or so is affected by some kind of interference pattern. The pattern is mostly stable, showing only a small amount of noise and flickering. It doesn't move much vertically.

After a minute or two, the pattern shrinks down to the bottom of the screen, and eventually disappears altogether.

It seems to be affected by the cold. Anecdotally, when I turn it on after it's been in a cold room, the problem seems worse, and it gradually improves as the laptop screen warms up.

**Questions:**

Electrically, what might be causing this? I.e. what could be the mechanism behind this? How could temperature (if that's what it is) cause the pattern to change?

**Thoughts:**

If I had to guess, I would think that this was something like a loose connector, or perhaps a bad solder joint. Something that's temperature sensitive. But I'm not familiar enough with the protocol between a laptop's motherboard and screen to be able to guess at the mechanism. I'm not even sure if it's a digital or analog signal.

The laptop is an Alienware M18 R2. (Dell doesn't list it on its webside any more, but here's a [review](https://www.laptopmag.com/reviews/laptops/alienware-m18x-r2) of it).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a loose driver cable, one that is supposed to be soldered or otherwise make good contact with the help of maybe conductive adhesive.

Temperature changes the materials involved, it may have an effect through thermal expansion that the cable makes better contact when the system is warm.